Trouble with Twilio whatsapp messaging, status 403
hope someone can assist, been beating my head against the wall for several months on this.
I'm developing an app that takes form values from the font end and process via the back end function below.
for some added context, I've spent the last few months trying to get programmable SMS to work, however could get approved for 10DLC registration, so today I tried pivoting to whatsapp, hoping to have better luck.
Also, I was able to get a sender approved for whatsapp by following Meta's verification process.
However I'm still getting the message below.
Please let me know if there is any more context required, this is my first time posting on here.
import twilio from "twilio";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const twilioNumber = process.env.TWIL_PHONE_NUMBER;
//const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

const twilioSMS = async (message) => {
  message.from = "whatsapp:" + twilioNumber;

  const twilioApiUrl = "https://sendsms-7310.twil.io/sendSMS";

  const body = new URLSearchParams({
    From: message.from,
    To: message.to,
    Body: message.body,
    MessagingServiceSid: "MG00788be0ae8f5420cb4a7b950bc9f9d5",
    StatusCallback: "https://status-callback-2523.twil.io/message-status",
  });

  try {
    const response = await fetch(twilioApiUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization:
          "Basic " +
          Buffer.from(`${accountSid}:${authToken}`).toString("base64"),
      },
      body: body.toString(),
    });

    console.log("Backend: twilioSMS response: ", response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending SMS via Twilio:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export default twilioSMS;

Response {
  size: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _events: [Object],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _eventsCount: 3,
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    stream: PassThrough {
      _events: [Object],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _eventsCount: 3,
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    boundary: null,
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    type: 'default',
    url: 'https://sendsms-7310.twil.io/sendSMS',
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: {
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'content-length': '64',
      'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf8',
      date: 'Fri, 12 Jul 2024 22:13:24 GMT'
    },
    counter: 0,
    highWaterMark: 16384
  }
}


Can you specify what you are trying to achieve? You mentioned the 10DLC onboarding and the WhatsApp sender process but both are admin tasks that are not related to code. What are you trying to build and what isn't working?
It would be helpful if you could reduce the question to the minimal amount of information that is necessary to understand your challenge.
